# Django copy instances bulk create

Tags: python, django, bulkinsert

What is the best way to copy django objects for bulk creating, when multiple fields may vary between instances?

for example i have:

```
objects_to_create = []
for i in range(5):
    new_obj = obj
    new_obj.pk = None
    new_obj.foo = i
    objects_to_create.append(new_obj)
M.objects.bulk_create(objects_to_create)
```

However, for all of these newly created objects, foo will have value 4, because bulk create is saving 5 instances of new_obj as it is at the end of the loop. Is there a way to create copies that can then be modified before saving?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use [`deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) to create object's copy:

```
import copy
objects_to_create = []
for i in range(5):
   new_obj = copy.deepcopy(obj)
   new_obj.pk = None
   new_obj.foo = i
   objects_to_create.append(new_obj)
M.objects.bulk_create(objects_to_create)
```